# Setting Explicit tag for Apple .m4a file with TagLib#

Tags: c#, .net, metadata, itunes, taglib-sharp

I'm using this method to add the `ITUNESADVISORY` tag:

```
static void SetExplicit(string file)
{
    var f = TagLib.File.Create(file);
    TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag customTag = (TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag)f.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Apple, true);
    var vector = new TagLib.ByteVector();
    vector.Add((byte)1);
    customTag.SetData("ITUNESADVISORY", vector, (int)TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleDataBox.FlagType.ContainsData);
    f.Save();
}
```

Except it doesn't work. It throws and exception (`type` cannot be `null`) on the `SetData(type, vector, flags)` line. Do I need to somehow add the DataBox first, or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *type* parameter of `customTag.SetData()` must be exactly 4 bytes, since it is used as the `BoxType` property for the `TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag` object that holds the tag data. The **ITUNESADVISORY** tag is actually identified using a `BoxType` containing `{114, 116, 110, 103}`, which translates into a string value of **rtng**.

```
static void SetExplicit(string file)
{
    var f = TagLib.File.Create(file);
    TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag customTag = (TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag)f.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Apple, true);
    var vector = new TagLib.ByteVector();
    vector.Add((byte)1);
    customTag.SetData("rtng", vector, (int)TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleDataBox.FlagType.ContainsData);
    f.Save();
}
```

**Note:** *By default, the* `Taglib.ByteVector` *methods create a 4-byte array, however, the data value of the **rtng** tag must contain only a single byte value.*

Valid values of the **rtng** tag are:

- `0` - No Rating (Content was never explicit to begin with).
- `1` - Explicit (Content contains offensive language).
- `2` - Clean (Content has been sanitized of offensive language).

---

### Alternate Code Example

I rewrote your sample code in a way which was easier for me to read at a glance. I am a beginning programmer, so I may have violated some de facto standards. I also changed the names of most of the variables to better reflect what they actually contain. For instance, the `tags` variable you called `customTag` holds nearly all of the tag and song data; it is not just the single tag you are trying to create or edit. Hopefully this helps some newbies like me.

```
static void SetExplicit(string file)
{
    var f = TagLib.File.Create(file);

    var tags = (TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleTag) f.GetTag(TagLib.TagTypes.Apple);

    TagLib.ByteVector customTagName = "rtng";
    TagLib.ByteVector customTagData = new byte[] { 1 };
    var customTagFlag = (UInt32)TagLib.Mpeg4.AppleDataBox.FlagType.ContainsData;

    tags.SetData(customTagName, customTagData, customTagFlag);

    f.Save();
}
```

Comment: No problem! Thanks for letting me know. Your question actually helped me figure some things out while trying to use TagLib in a PowerShell script.

Comment: Hey, that's great! I actually knew the answer almost all along, I just didn't realize that I had to use `rtng` tag. I was using `ITUNESADVISORY` :D Fortunately I found some code on Github that helped me realize that these tag names can only be 3-4 bytes long.